# I am trying to find a workaround for using ng-disabled in ie8

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I currently have an app which has 2 buttons that must both be disabled when either is clicked. Initially, I had decided to use `ng-disabled`, however, to my amazement it is not compatible with ie8.

I have been scouring the web for a solution but am unable to find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information on my problem do not hesitate to ask. 
Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have decided to try use `doucumentById` to set the buttons to disabled but still no luck. Clicking the first button will disable the first button, it should disable both, and clicking the second disables both buttons, as it should.

Comment: Please share code. Also, note that IE 8 is no longer supported by the Angular team as of 1.3, and they aren't very motivated to support it in versions prior to that.